# How to enable browse image in react native webview?

Tags: react-native, webview

I used input type file for browse image on my website. However on my app I used webview, it didn't work, when I clicked on button browse nothing happen.

Do you have any solution or other library for help me?

This is my code, but it didn't work.

```
<WebView
   style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}
    scalesPageToFit
    javaScriptEnabled
    domStorageEnabled
    startInLoadingState
    mixedContentMode="always"
   source={{uri: 'https://homexkh.com'}}
   />
```

Thank for answer.

Comment: Are you trying to browse images on a web server or browse the images on your device?

Comment: On my mobile used webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer on my question.

I found a library [React Native WebView - a Modern, Cross-Platform WebView for React Native](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview)

I just install and link successful then import it. It work.

**This library didn't work on Expo.**

If you have any solutions please share on this. Thank